# How to return extra "blank" rows based on return results in linq?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Is there a way to combine following two linqs? I have tried using `Union` method

```
dim result = query2.Union(query3).ToList()
```

but i get error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_4`3[System.Object,System.Object,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

I just want to have an extra blank row with every return row in query2,So if query 2 returns two rows then there should be two blank rows, i have tried adding another select on query2 with union but i get error message.

```
Dim query2 = (From e In dsSummary.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
              Group e By
                  DistNum = e("DistNum"),
                  DistName = e("DistName")
              Into Group
              Select New With {
                  .DistNum = DistNum,
                  .DistName = DistName,
                  .EventName = "Distributor Number Total",
                  .DiscountTotal = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("DiscountTotal")).ToString("C2"),
                  .NetTotal = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("NetTotal")).ToString("C2"),
                  .SummaryRow = "Y"
              })

Dim query3 = (From e In dsSummary.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
            Group e By
                DistNum = e("DistNum"),
                DistName = e("DistName")
            Into Group
            Select New With {
                .DistNum = DistNum,
                .DistName = "",
                .EventName = "Distributor Number Total",
                .DiscountTotal = 0.ToString("C2"),
                .NetTotal = 0.ToString("C2"),
                .SummaryRow = "Z"
            })
```

Comment: This is Linq-To-Objects([`Linq-To-DataSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/linq-to-dataset)), what has it to do with SQL or LINQ-To-SQL?

Comment: updated.........

Comment: You want the blank rows to be added at the end?

Comment: it can be any where as i have a field called summary row which i will use to sort and place the blank row at the right place.

Comment: Use query2.Concat(query3) for list merging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add "empty rows" at the end, one for every row in the query:

```
Dim emptyRows = From x In query2
                Select New With {.DistNum = "", .DistName = "", .EventName = "", .DiscountTotal = "", .NetTotal = "", .SummaryRow = ""}
Dim resultList = query2.Concat(emptyRows).ToList()
```

If you want them not to added to the end but use `SummaryRow` for the ordering, place the `OrderBy` before the `ToList()`.